# Copy document from links that doesn't same with data in database

Tags: php, mysql

I crawled pdf link from web, I want to copy the pdf that doesn't exist yet in database by check out the name of document (that I get from link) with the name of document that exist in database.
here's the code :

```
$input = explode(" ",trim(basename($pdfLink, ".pdf"),"() "));
$sql   = mysql_query("SELECT doc_name FROM tb WHERE doc_name ='$input'")or die(mysql_error());
if (!$sql){
    copy($pdfLink, $savePath . basename($pdfLink));
}
```

`$pdfLink` is string of PDFlinks. but, copy process didn't work. what's wrong? thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better for you to check count of related records in DB

```
$input = explode(" ",trim(basename($pdfLink, ".pdf"),"() "));
$sql   = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tb WHERE doc_name ='$input'")
         or die(mysql_error());
$row   = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
if ($row['cnt'] < 1){
  copy($pdfLink, $savePath . basename($pdfLink));
}
mysql_free_result($sql);
```

or to count affected rows:

```
$input = explode(" ",trim(basename($pdfLink, ".pdf"),"() "));
$sql   = mysql_query("SELECT doc_name FROM tb WHERE doc_name ='$input' LIMIT 1")
         or die(mysql_error());
$rows   = mysql_affected_rows($sql);
if ($rows < 1){
  copy($pdfLink, $savePath . basename($pdfLink));
}
mysql_free_result($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `SELECT` statement returns an empty set (i.e. does not find anything), it still returns a valid handle, which PHP interprets as true. So if no database error occurs, the variable `$sql` always results to true.